# Most basic/common words in spoken English

Tags: word-usage, frequency-analysis

I need a sorted list of the most frequent spoken English words for everyday situations. Think of the most important words for a beginner learning the language. When learning new words, you'd want to learn them in the order of their frequency or importance, that is, first the most basic ones.

There are many frequency lists which are compiled from written text, but for **spoken text**, I have not yet found anything usable. Examples:

- Most lists found online are not sorted by word frequency. They just list the top 100 or top 1000 words.
- https://1000mostcommonwords.com/1000-most-common-english-words/ seems to be what I'm looking for. However, it has 'sleep' on position 559, but 'syllable' on position 533 and 'vowel' on 479. I'm pretty sure that the majority of people uses the word 'sleep' much much more often than 'syllable' or 'vowel'. Then, 'develop' is at 437, 'morning' at 475. All the people saying several times "Good Morning" each day seem to not be counted in this list. Even stranger results in other languages.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English lists the top 100 words according to the Oxford English Corpus (OCE). This looks quite good, but I still think there is a bias towards written English. For example, I cannot find the words 'thank'/'thanks', 'morning', 'sleep', 'yes', 'no', 'last', and 'great' in the top-100 list. But the words 'people' and 'work' are there. In **spoken text**, is 'people' really more frequently used than 'great', 'yes' or 'thanks'?

I do not need anything rigorous. It just should not have an obvious bias towards written English, like the examples above. Furthermore, it does not matter whether filler "words" like 'uhm', 'ah', 'huh' are included in the list or not.

Bonus points if the list is also available in other languages (like 1000mostcommonwords.com), but this is not important.

Comment: Someone may find something better but here's the [general service list](http://jbauman.com/gsl.html) from 1953, it was the standard referrence for those compiling vocabularies for foreign learners of English, somewhat out of use now.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. Thanks, but this has the same bias towards written text. 'develop' and 'people' are around position 100, while 'morning' is at 497 (behind 'surface', 'pressure' and 'operation'), and 'yes' is at 743.

Comment: I'm not sure how a list of the most frequent spoken words could be compiled. The type of speech for which recordings and transcripts would be readily available for analysis is obviously going to be different to that used in private casual conversation.

Comment: The problem seems to be that there’s not really a corpus of people talking as they go about their daily lives. There is a corpus that has radio/tv transcripts but looking at that there is a noticeable bias towards words to do with things like politics, and some important words like “bathroom” are somewhere in obscurity because they’re  not used often for those mediums.

Comment: I see the problem. I'm asking if there is a solution. Maybe someone has compared the word frequencies of a Reality TV show, or of children's books, to the existing corpuses. This would give an indication of the bias, and could be used to correct it.